# Android - How to use custom font file containing multiple fonts

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

I am not very experienced with fonts, so this issue might be due to my ignorance.

I have a font file, Futura.tcc. In code I have the following:

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(am, "fonts/Futura.ttc");
editText.setTypeface(face);
```

This works for the basic Futura font. But, the file my client sent contains multiple font sub-types (if that is the proper term). I know `setTypeFace()` accepts a second parameter of type int that is the style. But, passing in various values does nothing.

If this file contains a font called 'Futura Light', how would I tell it to use that font, rather than just the regular Futura font?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find the ttc/ttf for "Futura Light" and drop it in the assets folder. Usually each "sub font" have their own separate file.

Then you just do:

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "futura_light.ttf");
editText.setTypeface(face);
```

**EDIT:**

I actually had it on my computer so I uploaded it for you: **[Download Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/64ib9dz98p4ll8z/Futura_%28Light%29.ttf)**

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate you passing along that file. Just for curiousity sake, is it then not possible to get sub-fonts from a file? For example, I also use Avenir. On my mac, I have one font file, with multiple fonts in it. Do I need to track down separate files?

Comment: As far as I know, yes that's correct. I've always just quickly googled it and found what I was looking for. I could be wrong though.